# Re-ordering the legend items in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with following data

```
marks   cut but xut
1   49  51  67
2   53  47  76
3   54  46  67
4   54  46  56
5   55  45  65
6   55  45  75
7   55  45  45
8   55  45  33
9   55  45  43
10  56  45  53
11  56  45  23
12  56  44  78
13  56  44  45
```

When I plot the graph I get get the legend as cut but xut , I want the legend to be as xut but and cut i.e. I want to re-order the legends and present them in a manner whichI need

below is the code which I have implemented

```
install.packages("plyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("reshape2")
library("plyr")
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")

data=read.csv("data.csv")
attach(data)
data$marks <- factor(data$marks, levels 
= data$marks[order(data$cut)])

c.data=melt(data, id.var="marks")
n.data = ddply(c.data,.(marks), transform, pos = cumsum(value) - 0.5*value)

n.data <- transform(n.data,variable = factor(levels = c("xut", "but", "cut")))

plot = ggplot(d.data, aes(x = marks, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",mapping = aes(x = value, fill = variable)) + scale_y_continuous( breaks=seq(0,100, by = 10))+geom_text(aes(label = value, y = pos), size = 3, face="bold", colour="white") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("455555","333333","335566"))  + theme(axis.line = element_line(),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60,hjust=1,colour="white"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="white"),axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank()) + labs(fill="")+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) + theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

Comment: I don't understand your description of the problem. When I run your code I get a legend that lists `a` and then `b`. Why would there be a `marks` level in the legend? I don't follow...

Comment: sorry for the confusion please check the code now

Comment: This is just a demo code i have multiple column tables i wanted for them as well

Comment: That's worse, now your code refers to a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: i had to edit the code as i am not supposed to share it here :(

Comment: Look, it's still not really clear what you're asking. If you just want the levels to appear in the legend in a different order, you can change the order of the levels in `variable`.

Comment: Post edited please check and remove the hold

Comment: I will probably note vote to reopen this. The code currently in your Q is not runnable: your `transform` call is incorrect, and you reference `d.data` which is never created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reorder the levels of the variable with the groups in the long or melted version of the data. For example, using your data

```
foo <- read.table(text="marks   cut but xut
1   49  51  67
2   53  47  76
3   54  46  67
4   54  46  56
5   55  45  65
6   55  45  75
7   55  45  45
8   55  45  33
9   55  45  43
10  56  45  53
11  56  45  23
12  56  44  78
13  56  44  45", header = TRUE)
```

Melt it into a suitable format

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
bar <- melt(foo, id = "marks")

> head(bar)
  marks variable value
1     1      cut    49
2     2      cut    53
3     3      cut    54
4     4      cut    54
5     5      cut    55
6     6      cut    55
```

Then set the levels on the `variable` factor containing the group labels

```
bar <- transform(bar,
                 variable = factor(variable, levels = c("xut", "but", "cut")))
```

Then plot

```
ggplot(bar) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = value, fill = variable))
```

As you don't show **any** plotting code I'm guessing what your actual plot code looks like, but as the above shows, at least the ordering is what you want...

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'pos' not found
this is the error i am facing

Comment: @Zack *Show your code*! You've edited away anything useful in that regard. Fix your question and I'll take a closer look. Impossible to say what you are screwing up without it.

Comment: Please check the code i need to remove it as soon as you see the code

Comment: @Zack Your error is coming from code that is *not* mine. We aren't here to debug your code for you. Note `pos` is not involved in any of my calls, and looks to originate in the `ddply()` call.

Comment: It was working fine before but once i implement the code you suggested it is giving me error

Comment: @Zack If my code **doesn't** include `pos`, then it is *not* a problem that I need to fix. And for crying out loud, **stop** removing things that are essential to your question by editing them out!!! Your `ggplot` call uses an input different to the output from `transform`. Like I said, we are not here to debug your code. Do you know where the error occurs? what does `traceback()` say.

Comment: so variable is unable to get the label name it is getting to <na>

Comment: I think the OP is posting bits of supposed-to-be-confidential code and then removing them in a (vain) hope to avoid exposing them too much. To the OP: (1) once you post it on a public site like SO, the cat is out of the bag anyway (users with sufficient reputation can see previous revisions); (2) if you want free help, you need to spend some time thinking about how to write reproducible code that mimics your problem -- reviewing http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 is often worthwhile.

Comment: thank you for the link ben edited my according to the link